# Calling an Api in Node js after data inserted into mariadb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb

I have a table in mariadb, say Table X, data is inserted to X by a different source.
I want to this to trigger an API in node js whenever new row is inserted into table X.

I tried using sequelize hooks, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.Adding code gives more clarity

Comment: You can use UDF ([User Defined Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-functions/)) and write your Database trigger accordingly